# Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path with Swagger

Tags: c#, json, swagger, deserialization

I am working on a project where I use `Swagger` for the API requests. 
I have a problem with `DeserializeObject`:
 when the application try to `deserialize` this parameter it goes in exception with this error:

> `Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 2, position 3`

**JSON:**

```
[
  {
    "code": "AAA111"
  },
  {
    "code": "BBB222"
  },
  {
    "code": "CCC333"
  },
  {
    "code": "DDD444"
  }
]
```

I searched in a lot of sites about this error, but nothing worked for me. 
I noticed something in particular: 
When I try to `deserialize` this `List` of `strings`, the parameter `Descriptor.ParamterType` equals to `List1`

> value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(stringValue,
> Descriptor.ParameterType, serializerSetting);

[image]

**Another info:** from `Swagger` where I pass this body request:

```
{
    "bo": "AA00",
    "dc": "0",
    "ce": "0",
    "lang": "EN",
    "cn": "0000000000",
    "eac": "X",
    "mat": [
        {
            "code": "AAA111"
        },
        {
            "code": "BBB222"
        },
        {
            "code": "CCC333"
        },
        {
            "code": "DDD444"
        }
    ]
}
```

For security reasons, I cannot show you the real parameters and values.

Comment: Your JSON looks perfectly valid: I suspect you may have removed the problem when trying to sanitise the request before posting it. Can you paste your *actual* request into an online JSON validator, or create a request that reproduces your issue but doesn't contain sensitive data to post here?

Comment: @canton7 I validated my JSON request, and it's OK. Even if change the request with another values, the problem is the same: when it tries to deserialize that part of code, it goes in error with this '{' char

Comment: What is contained in `stringValue`, in your screenshot?

Comment: this
`"[\r\n  {\r\n    \"code\": \"AAA111\"\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"code\": \"BBB222\"\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"code\": \"CCC333\"\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"code\": \"DDD444\"\r\n  }\r\n]"`

Comment: What is `Descriptor.ParameterType`?  Can you share a [mcve]?  Also, can you [edit] your question to share the full `ToString()` output of the exception, including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s) if any, **as text** rather than as a screen shot?  It's required here not to to use images for this purpose, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.